# Meshes.jl ERROR: UndefVarError: P2 not defined

Tags: julia

I am trying to run some code from the Meshes.jl test source code, and it fails. What am I missing?

```
using Meshes

points = P2[(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1), (0.5,0.5)]
#ERROR: UndefVarError: P2 not defined
#Stacktrace:
# [1] top-level scope
#   @ REPL[2]:1
```

The code is from here:
https://github.com/JuliaGeometry/Meshes.jl/blob/bcc08b0b53622f2578c61561fef91153c05c393b/test/mesh.jl#L176

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the *runtests.jl* file (https://github.com/JuliaGeometry/Meshes.jl/blob/bcc08b0b53622f2578c61561fef91153c05c393b/test/runtests.jl#L118), P2 is defined as an alias for `Point{2, Float64}`.

```
T = Float64
P1, P2, P3 = Point{1,T}, Point{2,T}, Point{3,T}
```

If you run these two lines, your example code will work.

Alternatively, you can define your points as:

```
points = Point[(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1), (0.5,0.5)]
```

Comment: If someone is using these as aliases (that is, if they are defined in the global scope), they should place `const` in front of the assignments, or there will be type instabilities. Using `T` as an alias for `Float64` seems like a pretty bad idea, though. Just write `const P1 = Point{1, Float64}` etc.